# How to correctly clone --recursive git repository on Windows?

Tags: windows, git, recursion, cygwin, command-prompt

#### How to correctly clone --recursive git repository on Windows?

My git version is:

```
git --version
git version 2.8.2
```

When I clone a repository with `--recursive` using this command line:

`git clone --recursive https://github.com/evandrocoan/SublimeTextStudio.git "D:/User/Dropbox/Applications/SoftwareVersioning/SublimeText/Data/Packages"`

And this were the console output: (everything ok, without errors)

```
D:\User\Dropbox\Applications\SoftwareVersioning\SublimeText>git clone --recursive https://github.com/evandrocoan/SublimeTextStudio.git "D:/User/Dropbox/Applications/SoftwareVersioning/Su
blimeText/Data/Packages"
Cloning into 'D:/User/Dropbox/Applications/SoftwareVersioning/SublimeText/Data/Packages'...
remote: Counting objects: 827, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (244/244), done.
remote: Total 827 (delta 139), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 563eceiving objects:
Receiving objects: 100% (827/827), 3.64 MiB | 691.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (452/452), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Submodule 'ANSIescape' (https://github.com/evandrocoan/SublimeANSI) registered for path 'ANSIescape'
Submodule 'BBCode' (https://github.com/evandrocoan/BBCode) registered for path 'BBCode'
Submodule 'Boxy Theme' (https://github.com/evandrocoan/st-boxy) registered for path 'Boxy Theme'
Submodule 'Package Control' (https://github.com/evandrocoan/package_control) registered for path 'Package Control'
Submodule 'SideBarEnhancements' (https://github.com/evandrocoan/SideBarEnhancements) registered for path 'SideBarEnhancements'
Submodule 'SublimeAmxxPawn' (https://github.com/evandrocoan/SublimeAmxxPawn) registered for path 'SublimeAmxxPawn'
Submodule 'SublimeNotepadPlusPlusTheme' (https://github.com/evandrocoan/SublimeNotepadPlusPlusTheme) registered for path 'SublimeNotepadPlusPlusTheme'
Submodule 'SublimeTextToolBar' (https://github.com/evandrocoan/SublimeTextToolBar) registered for path 'SublimeTextToolBar'
Submodule 'Theme - SoDaReloaded' (https://github.com/evandrocoan/SoDaReloaded-Theme) registered for path 'Theme - SoDaReloaded'
Submodule 'Theme - Soda' (https://github.com/evandrocoan/soda-theme) registered for path 'Theme - Soda'
Cloning into 'ANSIescape'...
remote: Counting objects: 200, done.
Receiving objects:   3% (6/200)remote: Total 200 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 200
Receiving objects: 100% (200/200), 45.36 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (120/120), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Submodule path 'ANSIescape': checked out 'd93f5ce408a28252c73d11a5b0b1b456162e8bac'
Cloning into 'BBCode'...
remote: Counting objects: 86, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
remote: Total 86 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 74
Unpacking objects: 100% (86/86), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Submodule path 'BBCode': checked out '51d4813dc2e7a99e2c8afa5ce1cf71bbebf1a88d'
Cloning into 'Boxy Theme'...
remote: Counting objects: 13403, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (58/58), done.
remote: Total 13403 (delta 28), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 13345
Receiving objects: 100% (13403/13403), 6.84 MiB | 410.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (7243/7243), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Submodule path 'Boxy Theme': checked out 'f5c8f1dd3f69df64ca0cd45dbd8f25456fc53e58'
Cloning into 'Package Control'...
remote: Counting objects: 4950, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (73/73), done.
remote: Total 4950 (delta 43), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 4877
Receiving objects: 100% (4950/4950), 1.73 MiB | 643.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3476/3476), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Submodule path 'Package Control': checked out '5195e29c0a8e12913d1fb7aaaf1370942d7f2409'
Cloning into 'SideBarEnhancements'...
remote: Counting objects: 1506, done.
remote: Total 1506 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1506
Receiving objects: 100% (1506/1506), 468.76 KiB | 517.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (940/940), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Submodule path 'SideBarEnhancements': checked out '3c7957f2446b442931c3731358a79750687059d2'
Cloning into 'SublimeAmxxPawn'...
remote: Counting objects: 287, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (123/123), done.
remote: Total 287 (delta 164), reused 282 (delta 159), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (287/287), 149.52 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (164/164), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Submodule path 'SublimeAmxxPawn': checked out 'df13519f98d3278fc025d01d3f39ff8ae2ff64a7'
Cloning into 'SublimeNotepadPlusPlusTheme'...
remote: Counting objects: 163, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Total 163 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 157
Receiving objects: 100% (163/163), 33.82 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (65/65), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Submodule path 'SublimeNotepadPlusPlusTheme': checked out '4cbca8d3717c4232ea4783579d82c45127623666'
Cloning into 'SublimeTextToolBar'...
remote: Counting objects: 48, done.
remote: Total 48 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 48
Unpacking objects: 100% (48/48), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Submodule path 'SublimeTextToolBar': checked out '04d97345937a9181b95c3b326ed1acc1bda60637'
Cloning into 'Theme - SoDaReloaded'...
remote: Counting objects: 1411, done.
remote: Total 1411 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1411eceiving objects
Receiving objects: 100% (1411/1411), 5.60 MiB | 424.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (703/703), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Submodule path 'Theme - SoDaReloaded': checked out 'ff9967a98734fc8f46e07bc7cb86115d325c9225'
Cloning into 'Theme - Soda'...
remote: Counting objects: 3156, done.
remote: Total 3156 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 3156
Receiving objects: 100% (3156/3156), 5.70 MiB | 366.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1157/1157), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Submodule path 'Theme - Soda': checked out 'd47df56b20741eda7ada4d1ed7e730bc4203b0d3'

D:\User\Dropbox\Applications\SoftwareVersioning\SublimeText>
```

All the sub-modules end up within a `.git` file, instead of a `.git` folder, containing its git info:

[image: Imgur]

That `.git` file contents are:

```
gitdir: /cygdrive/d/User/Dropbox/Applications/SoftwareVersioning/SublimeText/Data/Packages/.git/modules/SublimeNotepadPlusPlusTheme
```

The file should probably be a Linux symlink, but worthless on windows. It is all absolute, a horrible thing as the `Main` repository folder is just one level above. It should be relative with `../`.

On the folder `Data/Packages/.git/modules/`, I got all the submodules `.git` folders:

[image: Imgur]

And when I open the master repository with Smartgit, it shows all my cloned sub-modules as `not found`:

[image: Imgur]

Comment: I have cloned recursive repos (with submodules) many times on Windows and have never had this problem. Which git client are you using? Have you tried cloning outside the Dropbox folder by any chance?

Comment: Ok I just cloned the same repo and yes the .git in submodule directories are files instead of folders

Comment: I am using this git: "D:\User\Documents\Cygwin64\usr\libexec\git-core\git.exe", it says version 2.8.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cygwin git prefers posix path, so instead of

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/evandrocoan/SublimeTextStudio.git "D:/User/Dropbox/Applications/SoftwareVersioning/SublimeText/Data/Packages"
```

you should have tried:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/evandrocoan/SublimeTextStudio.git "/Cygdrive/d/User/Dropbox/Applications/SoftwareVersioning/SublimeText/Data/Packages"
```

The result has a `.git` folder.

```
Packages/.git
Packages/.git/hooks
Packages/.git/info
Packages/.git/logs
Packages/.git/logs/refs
Packages/.git/logs/refs/heads
Packages/.git/logs/refs/remotes
Packages/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin
Packages/.git/modules
Packages/.git/modules/ANSIescape
Packages/.git/modules/ANSIescape/hooks
Packages/.git/modules/ANSIescape/info
Packages/.git/modules/ANSIescape/logs
...
Packages/.git/modules/Theme - SoDaReloaded/refs/tags
Packages/.git/objects
Packages/.git/objects/info
Packages/.git/objects/pack
Packages/.git/refs
Packages/.git/refs/heads
Packages/.git/refs/remotes
Packages/.git/refs/remotes/origin
Packages/.git/refs/tags
Packages/.githooks
```

Anyway as you were looking for a git repository compatible with a Windows application as SmartGit you need to use the Windows version of Git.
As you have already discovered.

Answer (score 1):

Now removed that git, and installed this other https://git-scm.com/download/win:

```
git --version
git version 2.10.0.windows.1
```

It stills creating the `.git` file, but now the symlink contents are relative:

```
gitdir: ../.git/modules/ANSIescape
```

And it is being correctly detected by Smartgit.